# any significance in fiddler to ‘Aggregate Session’ time and Sequence (clock) time being very different?

Tags: fiddler

We have a ASP.NET C# website (not MVC) that consists of a half dozen Pages. One of them is very large, consisting of several  3rd party controls (from Telerik, FarPointSpread and a few from the Ajax Control Toolkit) and about 15,000 lines of code.
 This particular page, which is invoked by way of a response.redirect command from a prior page, has always loaded very slowly. Once we click on the button it takes quite a while (perhaps 10 seconds) for the new page to appear. While this is not especially acceptable what is much worse is that, when the new page actually does load, it takes quite a bit more time (perhaps yet another 10 seconds) for the various elements of the page (drop down lists, buttons, scroll bars and the like) to become available to the user.
Recently we started to use Fiddler to try and get some statistical information to help us improve on this. One of my associates, who has access to one of our Web Servers, has been using fiddler to monitor the performance of this program. His findings are:
•   Our compression routines seem to be working. Much of the static information required by the program is coming from cache.
•   Some of the images come back with a return code of 401, but these images are eventually made available.
•   Fiddler reports an ‘Aggregate Session’ time of approximately 4 seconds. 
•   It also reports a ‘Sequence (clock)’ time of approximately 16 seconds.
•   When we use fiddler to acquire statistics for any of the other programs (which are all much smaller and don’t have the issues this larger program has) we do not see the large difference between the ‘Aggregate Session’ time and the ‘Sequence (clock)’ time

Answer (score 0):

Sequence time being longer than the aggregate session time means that the client is idle for some period of time and not making requests, perhaps due to slow-running JavaScript on the client.

The 401s are from HTTP Authentication requests from the server.